# form doesn't save foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a Product, which has a foreign key to a Category model, but the foreign key is never saved to the database for some reason.

This is my form

```
<%= nested_form_for @product do |f| %>
<div>
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id]}, :include_blank => true %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :price %><br>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %><br>
</div>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and controller

```
class Admin::ProductsController < AdminController

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
        flash[:notice] = "You have added #{@product.name}"
        redirect_to admin_products_path
    else
        flash[:error] = "An error occured"
        render "new" 
    end     
  end

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update(product_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Succesfully updated #{@product[:name].titleize}"
      redirect_to admin_products_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "An error occred update #{@product[:name].titleize}"
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "You succesfully removed #{@product.name}"      
    else 
      flash[:error] = "An error occured trying to remove #{@product.name}"
    end
    redirect_to admin_products_path
  end

  private

    def product_params
            params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :category_id, :description,
        stocks_attributes: [ :id, :size, :amount, :_destroy ])
        end

end
```

Server log:

```
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+rHOeT8GvAB4zF5QjR1RLJiFyh38d+bgwgA4KS6Fiz8=", "product"=>{"category_id"=>"1", "name"=>"awfsdsd", "price"=>"111", "description"=>"adasdada"}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
  Admin Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins"  WHERE "admins"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: category_id
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 30ms

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid - Validation failed: Category can't be blank:
```

Comment: Can you share the server log generated upon form submission. Add it in the question.

Comment: updated original post, I can see that I get an "Unpermitted parameters: category_id", but I don't understand this, since I permit in through the strong parameters

Comment: Why is your form nested, and to what?

Comment: My bad, I didn't include the nested form for simplicity, it has to do with size/stock, but works fine

Comment: Do the following: Load your form, comment all your routes and submit it. Then you will know where exactly you are posting, because it seems to me that controllers have got a bit mangled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have two controllers, one named `ProductsController` and other named  `Admin::ProductsController`. If you notice the error log, you would see that the request is going to `ProductsController#create` and NOT `Admin::ProductsController#create`.

You have permitted `category_id` in `Admin::ProductsController` **but not in `ProductsController`**

Update the `form` as below:

```
<%= nested_form_for [:admin, @product] do |f| %>
```

So, upon form submission it is directed to correct controller i.e., `Admin::ProductsController`.

**UPDATE**

> *but I only have a "show" action in ProductsController*

Update the routes for `ProductsController` as below:

```
resources :products, only: [:show]
```

instead of

```
resources :products
```

Comment: but I only have a "show" action in ProductsController, and the other attributes do pass?

Comment: hmm..it should work. Let's debug this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: @ArupRakshit Please rollback your last edit as you removed my updated answer.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Its Okay